# Check element class by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How do you check if the class that is assigned to a div? For example, I want to check if a div has a class of `header-link` then it should alert a message box similar to this:

```
$('.header a').click(function()
{
    if($(this).classname == 'header-link')
    {
        alert('the element has the class name already');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass('header-link');
    }
});
```

The `classname` I put in there is an example I need to make it check if it has the class assigned or not... (even when jQuery has assigned it dynamically).

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're checking if it already has the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$('.header a').click(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('header-link'))
    {
        alert('the element has the class name already');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass('header-link');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct check is [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) like this:

```
$('.header a').click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('header-link')) {
    alert('the element has the class name already');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('header-link');
  }
});
```

but...do you even need this check?
If the element *already* has the class [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) won't add a duplicate, so if that's your worry don't check, just call [`.addClass('header-link')`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) like this:

```
$('.header a').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('header-link');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `$(this).hasClass('header-link')` function
It returns true if the element has the class you specify

edit: updated for validity

Answer (score 1):

[`$(this).hasClass("header-link")`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)